# Перебор коллекции с присвоением значений (Java 8 Stream API)

Tags: java-stream, java-8

Добрый день! Недавно начал изучать Java 8, а конкретно Stream API, и
пока не разобрался во всех возможностях.

Есть 2 похожих класса - `User` и `UserWithAge`

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class UserWithAge {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Отличаются они, очевидно, только наличием-отсутствием поля age.

У нас также есть `List <User> users`, заполненный определенным кол-вом юзеров без возраста.

Задача: создать `List<UserWithAge> usersWithAge`, скопировать туда всех юзеров из `List <User> users`, и присвоить им всем одинаковый возраст (например, 27).

Как это реализовать с помощью **Java8 Stream API**, без использования циклов?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужно использовать метод `List.stream()`, чтобы получить stream экземпляров `User`, воспользоваться `Stream.map()`, чтобы для каждого экземпляра `User` создать экземпляр `UserWithAge` и выставить возраст, а затем методом `Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())` вернуть новую коллекцию.

Comment: Правильный ответ здесь, если кому-то понадобится
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683590/list-iteration-setting-values-with-java-8-streams-api/42689441#42689441